# Adding shop title in the Shop page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How i can show the product’s vendor name after the product title in the shop page in Woocommerce ?
i try add this code at the end of the file **functions.php** but not working !!

```html
/**
 * Print the product's vendor name before the product title in the loop.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wc_vendors_name_loop() {
 $vendors = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'shop_vendor' );

 if ( $vendors && ! is_wp_error( $vendors ) ) {
  foreach ( $vendors as $vendor ) {
   $all_vendors[] = $vendor->name;
  }

  $vendors = join( ", ", $all_vendors );

  echo '<span class="shop_vendors">' . $vendors . '</span>';
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'wc_vendors_name_loop', 20 );
```

Comment: Do you have a taxonomy called `shop_vendor` registered?

Comment: yes it called vendor

Comment: What do you get if you `var_dump($vendors);`?